# React dynamically rendered component not updating

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a list of components using map function in render. When I change state, render function is called as expected but my component is not updated. 
I've made a sample codesandbox here

https://codesandbox.io/s/nk24mr55om

What am I doing wrong? 
I've added some console logs and it look like secret content should be displayed but it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your item is pushed into the `items` array, it will not be updated, ever.  A solution to this would be to convert the items you push into arrow functions that will get a `show` parameter :

```
items.push(show => 
    <div>
      {show && <div>I'm secret</div>}
      My content
      <br />
      <input
        type="button"
        onClick={showSecret}
        value="Show secret content"
      />
    </div>
  );
```

And then call it in the mapping of your render :

```
return <div key={index}>{item(show)}</div>;
```

However, with this solution, clicking on one button will cause every item to show their secret element, if this isn't the behavior you expect and want every item to act on its own, I suggest creating a hook for each item. And ahev them store their own `show` variable in their state.

Comment: I understand what you have done. What I don't understand why my example doesn't work. You can see that "show" state has changed and that triggered rerender... Do I need to think about items as children of container and I need to pass props to it? But why does showSecret function works then? Is it creating a closure and captures the state when it's first time rendered?

Comment: Well, when you call `push`, your item is created depending of the current value of `show`. Since you are not reconstruction the items in this array ever, they are not getting updated. Also, yes, I would recommend thinking of items as child components to isolate their behavior from their parent

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience yet with react hooks, but i tried to understand whats going on. 
The variable items you refer to is neither a prop nor in the state of your component, i would make the component stateful and initialize items in the state.

Maybe there is a better way with react hooks that someone else can give

Comment: I have update my example.. I used state in my render... that was a typo